# Convert Decimal to Fraction

Tags: javascript, mathematics

This code below converts number from decimal to fraction. I don't know if there's a better way or better methods to do this job so any advice would be appreciated.

```
const toFraction = (inputNumber) => {
  // Only two digits after decimal point
  inputNumber = inputNumber.toFixed(2);

  // destructure number
  let [int, dec] = inputNumber
    .toString()
    .split(".")
    .map((el) => parseInt(el));

  // Round it up to nearst multiple of 5
  dec = Math.ceil(dec / 5) * 5;

  // Keep Dividing until it's impossible
  const divide = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2];
  let hundred = 100;
  let notOver = true;
  while (notOver) {
    notOver = false;
    for (let num of divide) {
      if (dec % num === 0 && hundred % num === 0) {
        dec /= num;
        hundred /= num;
        notOver = true;
      }
    }
  }
  return int === 0 ? `${dec}${hundred}` : `${int} ${dec}/${hundred}`;
};
```

Comment: Why limit it to 2 decimal places?

Comment: I have used it in a project that only needs two decimal points but you're right. I'll edit it to cover more digits

Comment: I suggest that you also add few test cases; with "console.log" outputs.

Comment: You seem to have missed a "/" in the first part of the output test `${dec}/${hundred}`

Comment: Thanks for advice! I've added tests and missing "/"

Comment: Great. You had my upvote.

Comment: Please don't change or add to the code in your question after you have received answers.  This makes it hard to understand the answers with respect to the version of code that they are referring to.  You can put the improvements in a new follow-up question instead.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can remove the `toString()` bit from here:

```
  let [int, dec] = inputNumber
    .toString()
    .split(".")
    .map((el) => parseInt(el));
```

`toFixed` returns a string. So, there is no need to call `toString` again.

---

The calculation part:

If the decimal part is `12`, your output is `3/25`. How do you get this? You get the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) between 12 and 100 and divide both of them with it. GCD of 12 and 100 is 4. So, (12/4) / (100/4)

There's already a simple recursive implementation of [euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Implementations) for that:

```
function gcd(a, b)
    if b = 0
        return a
    else
        return gcd(b, a mod b)
```

You can get the `precision` required as an option parameter which defaults to a predefined `MAX_PRECISION`. Get the GCD between the `dec` and 10 <sup>precision</sup> (eg: 100 for precision = 2)

```js
const MAX_PRECISION = 5

function toFraction(inputNumber, precision = MAX_PRECISION) {
  let [int, dec] = inputNumber
                      .toFixed(precision)
                      .split(".")
                      .map(n => +n)
                      
  const powerOf10 = 10 ** precision,
        gcd = getGCD(dec, powerOf10),
        fraction = `${dec/gcd}/${powerOf10/gcd}`;
  
  return int ? `${int} ${fraction}` : fraction
};

function getGCD(a, b) {
  if (!b) return a;

  return getGCD(b, a % b);
};

console.log( toFraction(1.14)   );
console.log( toFraction(5.71)   );
console.log( toFraction(3.34)   );
console.log( toFraction(5.1044) );
console.log( toFraction(0.67)   );
console.log( toFraction(0.84)   );
```

Comment: Thanks for your great solution. Actually i round the number to nearest multiple  of 5 so  0.12 becomes 0.15 and it's get divided by 5 and result become 3/20

Comment: @user3756068 Is it required to round it to nearest multiple of 5? You can still add that part to the code.

Comment: I'm using this code for a food recipe ingredients to calculate amount of the unit. It can be more precise but in this case it's not required.

Comment: The above information that the code is used in a food recipe should have gone into the question instead. It's important to have these details in the description since then we can decide whether the precision is good enough.